Help with beginner Arduino project
In a nutshell I am trying to use an ultrasonic sensor to display the distance from an object on an I2C LCD.
I ran it through the simulation but for some reason the LCD is not turning on or displaying any data at all.
What's shown in the picture is what is occurring in the tinker cad simulation. Maybe the SCL and SDA pins are not hooked up right.

#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>
// Initialize the I2C LCD
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, 16, 2); // Adjust address (0x27 or 0x3F) if needed
// Define pins for the ultrasonic sensor
const uint8_t trigPin = 9;
const uint8_t echoPin = 10;
void setup() {
  // Initialize the I2C LCD
  lcd.init();      // Initialize the LCD
  lcd.backlight(); // Turn on the backlight
  // Initialize the ultrasonic sensor pins
  pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  // Start the serial communication
  Serial.begin(9600);
}
void loop() {
  // Send a pulse to the ultrasonic sensor
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
  digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
  // Read the pulse duration from the echo pin
  uint16_t duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
  // Calculate the distance in centimeters
  uint16_t distance = duration * 0.034 / 2;
  // Display the distance on the LCD screen
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Distance: ");
  lcd.print(distance);
  lcd.print(" cm");
  // Print the distance to the serial monitor
  Serial.print("Distance: ");
  Serial.print(distance);
  Serial.println(" cm");
  // Wait 500ms before taking the next measurement
  delay(500);
}


Hi Rohan, welcome here! What does "it is not working" mean, precisely? You need to ask a definitive question on this question and answer site :)

Rohan, please [edit] your question, select the block of code and press the { } button to format it as code. Delete all the blank lines. Preview the post before submitting it. Also any text in your diagram is illegible so we can't see how you've connected them or what the part numbers are.

I fixed my post. Hopefully the new information helps!

I apologize for the inconvenience.

@RohanMarion Are you using the library as per the manual and examples? So you don't need to init I2C before blindly starting to initialize the display? I wonder if this is an electrical engineering issue at all, if it's simply about Arduino and there is Arduino.SE for Arduinos.

I am using the LiquidCrystal library

I am not great at writing firmware so I ran some code through chat gtp and it might have added the init. I took a twist off an online project where they used a non i2c module and tried to see if chat gtp could personalize it.

So you are using ChatGPT generated code? Please do not waste time by generating code with ChatGPT and asking why it does not work. ChatGPT is taught with websites about people asking what's wrong with their code so it will likely inject mistakes as it does not know what the working code is supposed to look like.

forget the ultrasonic sensor for now ... start with the  LCD ... run example code that comes with the library

does the display board use a backlight? And does the add-on I2C module include a small trim-potentiometer? If so, adjust to optimize contrast.

Did you try the I2C address of 0x27 instead of 0x3f? Run I2C scanner sketch to verify the I2C address.

You are missing the SCL connection and using ChatGPT generated code.
Those two things alone will make it not work, so there's too many points of failure. Please use human-written code examples.
